# How to count all the method calls in JDK using Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have to count all the methods in JDK, for each class, count the method calls it received;
for each method, count the number of times this method is called;

Hint: Use Eclipse JDT to create Abstract Syntax tree.

Can any body please explain how should I approach this problem. A brief algorithm would be great help.
Thanks

Comment: Google 'JDT AST Tutorial'. You will find some good explainations and examples.

Comment: @Joachim AST i can create, but i wanted a logical explanation that how will an AST help in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach your problem using the below steps:

1. First convert your java class to a `CompilationUnit` so that it can be
   traversed.
2. Then use the `ASTVisitor` pattern to visit the
   `MethodDeclaration` node (method call)
3. Do a reference search for the
   `MethodDeclaration` using JDT `SearchEngine` capabilities

Refer the below posts:

- [Eclipse create CompilationUnit from .java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166862/eclipse-create-compilationunit-from-java-file/11168301#11168301)
- [How to convert AST to JDT Java model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813202/how-to-convert-ast-to-jdt-java-model/15827754#15827754)
- [How to get all the references of static field with JDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493613/how-to-get-all-the-references-of-static-field-with-jdt/14497745#14497745)